# Stop / Abort Ajax Request without triggering error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to capture all ajax request on a page stop/abort some of the request depending on the some checking we do. Initially **jqXHR.abort();** works but the problem is that it is executing error event of all the request we aborted, which I do not want.

A sample snippet of what I created is like below.

```
var newajaxOptions;
$( ":button" ).on("click", function () {
    var URL = "#";
    $.ajax({
        url: URL,
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        success: function(){
            alert("AJAX SUCCESS");
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("AJAX ERROR");
        }
    });            
});


$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, jqXHR, ajaxOptions) {
    alert("BLOCKED");
    //set options to global variable so can re initiate ajax call later 
    newajaxOptions = ajaxOptions;
    jqXHR.abort();
});
```

P.S As a limitation I am not allowed to make any modification to the ajax request so I can only intercept the all the request check on the details stop those which are not allowed to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jqXHR can be really helpful

```
if(jqXHR.aborted)
    return;
```

And Script:

```
var newajaxOptions;
$( ":button" ).on("click", function () {
    var URL = "#";
    $.ajax({
        url: URL,
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        success: function(){
            alert("AJAX SUCCESS");
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            if(jqXHR.aborted)
                return;
            alert("AJAX ERROR");
        }
    });
});


$( document ).ajaxSend(function(event, jqXHR, ajaxOptions) {
    alert("BLOCKED");
    //set options to global variable so can re initiate ajax call later 
    newajaxOptions = ajaxOptions;
    jqXHR.abort();
});
```

---

#### Edit: *Throw hack*

```
var newajaxOptions;
$( ":button" ).on("click", function () {
    var URL = "#";
    $.ajax({
        url: URL,
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        success: function(){
            alert("AJAX SUCCESS");
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            //if(jqXHR.aborted)
            //  return;
            alert("AJAX ERROR");
        }
    });
    alert("After Button Click");
});


$( document ).ajaxSend(function(event, jqXHR, ajaxOptions) {
    alert("BLOCKED");
    throw "Your request is evil! Stop right now!";
});
```

This is something like "hack" in this case. `Throw` works in every browser and **side effect** is interrupt of current stack. But be careful `alert("After Button Click");` is also in current stack and will never execute, when you throw something.

More about:

[`throw` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw)

[error handling using `try...catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

Comment: Thanks Krzysiek for the answer. I have little bit of dilemma though, we are not allowed to changed the codes on the ajax call manually, is there a way to add the **if** statement dynamically in the **ajaxSend** method?

Comment: Tried the changes the error function of the ajax request still triggered.P.S I can't add **if(jqXHR.aborted) return;** to the ajax request as in our real setup we cannot touch the **$.ajax()** due to some restrictions that is why we are capturing the ajax request using **ajaxSend**

Comment: Maybe `throw 'stop!';` instead abort ?

Comment: One question, will throw 'stop!'; work across different browser?

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to reset the error event in your ajaxSend

```
$( document ).ajaxSend(function(event, jqXHR, ajaxOptions) {
    alert("BLOCKED");
    //set options to global variable so can re initiate ajax call later 
    newajaxOptions = ajaxOptions;

    ajaxOptions.error = null;

    jqXHR.abort();
});
```